# What are the mathematical steps used to get this $42=(-80538738812075974)³ + 80435758145817515³ + 12602123297335631³$?

Tags: number-theory, computer-science, diophantine-equations, wolfram-alpha

I have accrossed this representation in cubic sum  $42=(-80538738812075974)³ + 80435758145817515³ + 12602123297335631³$ at [this website](https://aperiodical.com/2019/09/42-is-the-answer-to-the-question-what-is-80538738812075974%C2%B3-80435758145817515%C2%B3-12602123297335631%C2%B3/) but am confused how mathematicains proved this , Now Is this representation as cubic sum were  proved using Computer or before using computer there are some theoritical steps which are used for application to computer ? And can someone use Wolfram mathematica for getting this kind of representation ?

Comment: Brutal computation, used something like half a million PCs.  See e.g. [this](https://www.sciencealert.com/the-sum-of-three-cubes-problem-has-been-solved-for-42)

Comment: In [this paper,](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40993-019-0162-1) they say a bit more about the actual algorithms used